How to Automatically Separate Concatenated Email Addresses with Semicolons in an ASP.NET TextBox Using JavaScript?
I am working on an ASP.NET Web Forms application where users need to enter multiple email addresses into a TextBox. Sometimes, users enter email addresses without any separators (e.g., binu.combinu.ae), and I need to automatically separate these with semicolons (;) when the input field loses focus.
I've implemented a basic solution using JavaScript to handle the blur event, but I'm facing issues when trying to intelligently split email addresses based on potential separators like "@" or ".".

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Email Separator</title>
     <script>

function formatEmails() {
const emailInput = document.getElementById('<%= emailInput.ClientID %>'); // Replace with your input ID
let emailString = emailInput.value.trim();


const emailRegex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})/g;

let result = '';
let match;
let lastIndex = 0;`your text`


while ((match = emailRegex.exec(emailString)) !== null) {
Add the matched email to the result
result += match[0] + ';';
lastIndex = emailRegex.lastIndex;
             }

Handle any remaining text that could be a partial email
if (lastIndex < emailString.length) {
result += emailString.substring(lastIndex).replace(/;/g, '') + ';';
            }

emailInput.value = result;
      }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const emailInput = document.getElementById('<%= emailInput.ClientID %>');
emailInput.addEventListener('blur', formatEmails); (unfocus)
         });
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="emailInput" runat="server" placeholder="Enter email addresses" />
         </div>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html> 


How can I improve my JavaScript function to reliably separate concatenated email addresses with semicolons in an ASP.NET Web Forms application? Are there any best practices or more robust regex patterns I should consider for this task?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You could try something like this:
HTML:
<html>
<head>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function process(){
    $("#output").html(separateEmailsBySemicolon($("#emails").val()));
}

function separateEmailsBySemicolon(emailList) {
  // Regular expression to match email addresses with optional leading/trailing spaces
  const emailRegex = /\s*([^\s<>@]+@[^\s<>@]+)\s*/g;

  // Extract email addresses using the regex
  const emailArray = emailList.match(emailRegex).map(match => match.trim());

  // Join the email addresses with semicolons
  const separatedEmails = emailArray.join(';');

  return separatedEmails;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
      <label>Email Addresses</label>
      <input type="test" id="emails" oninput="process();" />
      <hr/>
      <label>Processed</label>
      <span id="output"></span>
    </div>
</html>

